# Smooth scroll to top or bottom of page with javascript,jquery on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, smoothing

I have a one page website which is divided into two parts on horizontal mobile view. So am trying to create a scroll/swipe effect to top or bottom of the page. I tried this code of detection

```
var bottomofDoc = $(".main_container").height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(top < cur_top){
            direction = 'down';
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 600);
            console.log(direction);
        }else{
            direction = 'up';
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            console.log(direction);
        }
        top = cur_top;
    });
```

But it works buggy,with flickering and when i scroll once it continue doing actions many times.
Any ideas how to achive smooth scrolling to top or bottom

Comment: 1. http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/ 2. You probably want to introduce a flag and/or timer to not make more animate calls while one is still running.

Comment: I tried but it did not help @CBroe

Comment: Well we can’t help you if that’s all you are giving us. _Show_ us what you tried, and with what results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
     $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(){
          if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname){
               var target = $(this.hash);
               target = target.length ? target:$('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
               if(target.length){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                         scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
               }
           }
     });
});
```

Comment: I dont have click @Brachu19